# How to test only cmd.exe processes with NSClient if they are running? I want to implement it into Nagios

Tags: linux, windows, nagios

I have an windows server and i want to test the cmd.exe processes if they are running with nagios (NSClient) do you have some tips how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the command prompts 'tasklist' command?

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"
```

That would display all processes having the cmd.exe name, such as:

```
Image Name                PID      Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
cmd.exe                      12676 RDP-Tcp#0                  2      6,696 K
```

There should be some examples of how to incorporate this output into a check in the NSClient install.  Try 'tasklist /?' for help and options available for the command.

Comment: Yeah, but i have multiple cmds running and i want to test everyone, i mean i cant distinguish them.

Comment: Are you really interested in the cmd.exe processes, or perhaps what those shells are actually running?

Comment: the cmd.exe's are running processes but i cant test them by name